# How to fix procfile not showing?

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I am trying to make my Discord bot, [located here](https://github.com/eramedia-coding/BS-X-Bot) on Github, but my settings from my `Procfile` are not showing up.

I have tried checking the file is only `procfile`, remaking the file, changing the code.

```
worker node bot.js
```

I expect Heroku to run `node bot.js` but I get just the default `npm start`, No worker stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the file is called `Procfile`, with a capital P, not `procfile`. You use both versions in your question but only `Procfile` is correct.
2. Add a colon after the process type:

   ```
   worker: node bot.js
   ```

Comment: ID 0f718348-cf98-4517-a430-015b6d81681b
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 10.x...
       Downloading and installing node 10.16.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.9.0
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules

Comment: -----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       audited 140 packages in 0.782s
       found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: -----> Build
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       audited 140 packages in 0.816s
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules

Comment: -----> Build succeeded!
 !     This app may not specify any way to start a node process
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type
-----> Discovering process types
 ~     Mis-cased procfile detected; ignoring.
 ~     Rename it to Procfile to have it honored.
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 20.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v21
       https://bs-x-computer.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

Comment: and yes, It didnt fit on One message.

Comment: That looks like your app being built. It's what you're supposed to see. And it very clearly shows that you *haven't* done point 1: "Mis-cased procfile detected; ignoring."

Comment: Right, because file is called `procfile` (or some other variation), not `Procfile`.

Comment: but the file on github is the same as the one you are saying.
(https://github.com/eramedia-coding/BS-X-Bot/blob/master/procfile)

Comment: Again, that file is called _`procfile`_, all lower-case. It must be called _`Procfile`_, with a capital P. `procfile` and `Procfile` are different filenames.

Comment: What does "doesn't show" mean? Be specific. Please read [ask].

Comment: It is still only 
"Web: node start"

Comment: Well you don't have any web process defined. Have you scaled up a `worker` dyno formation? And I'm still not clear where you're seeing that. Again, please read [ask].

Comment: and that feature is only for Professionals, while I'm using the free version.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: [it is stated here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling) that I need to upgrade. I am on the free version, witch doesn't allow that.

Comment: That doesn't say anything about not being able to use worker dynos. You just can't use _multiple_ dynos. You only need _one_: scale `web` down to zero and scale `worker` up to one.

Comment: And now I have an error on startup. I will make a diffrent one for that, but it is fixed now. Turns out trying to push it through Github's website is hard.